# The findMatches function has disappeared

Tags: r, find, match

Recently, I wrote a R script, and it worked perfectly.

However, when I ran the script today, I cannot find the `findMatches()` function in R anymore. I cannot even find any information about it in internet anymore.

In my script, it should be a function from package `Biobase`, but I cannot find this function even in this package?

Basically this function is used to match the index in 2 vectors, and it returns 2 indexes from both the two vectors.

Could anyone help me to correct my memory and confirm me that there is such a function.

Comment: Also, try `library(sos); findFn("findMatches")`. And note that there's also a `find.matches` function in `Hmisc`

Comment: It's probably been deprecated since it's not in the [biobase docs](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/manuals/Biobase/man/Biobase.pdf)

Comment: @docendo discimus, Thanks a lot for the great package! I found the findMatches() fuction,  it is in `S4Vectors` package.